# React-native - Loop through array and create markers on a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and js and the whole 'state' concept. Anyways, I'm trying to loop through an array of car dealers with the value lat, lng and boolean (open or not). This is what the code looks like now and I'm wondering how the MapView.Marker code should look for that to work. Thanks

```
  <MapView style={styles.map}
    region ={{
    latitude:40.758927,
    longitude:-73.984981,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1,
 }}
 >
<MapView.Marker
  coordinate={{
    latitude:40.758927,
    longitude:-73.984981,
  }}
    title={'Ferrari dealer'}
    description={'Currently closed'}
    />

    </MapView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
let markers = this.state.cardDealers.map(dealer => (
  <MapView.Marker
    key={dealer.id}
    coordinate={{
      latitude: dealer.lat,
      longitude: dealer.lng,
    }}
    title={dealer.title}
    description={dealer.open ? 'Open' : 'Currently closed'}
  />
));

return (
  <MapView style={styles.map}
      region ={{
      latitude:40.758927,
      longitude:-73.984981,
      latitudeDelta: 0.1,
      longitudeDelta: 0.1,
   }}
  >
    {markers}
  </MapView>
)
```

You might find [React documentation on lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) helpful.